# Spring Contracts generated from Spring RestDocs: ignoring headers

Tags: spring-cloud-contract, spring-restdocs

TL;DR: I commented on [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/455#issuecomment-432626484) and got asked to open a new ticket, but then realized this is more of a question as Spring RestDocs provides a way to achieve what I want (ignoring unimportant headers in contracts) with [operation preprocessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/api/org/springframework/restdocs/operation/preprocess/Preprocessors.html). So here we are, on our friendly SoF

The problem is I am trying to generate contracts starting from a `RestDocs` test (using `RestAssured` and `junit5` if it matters). Test setup (in Kotlin) looks like:

```
private val defaultDocument = document("{method_name}", SpringCloudContractRestDocs.dslContract())
lateinit var spec: RequestSpecification
@BeforeEach
internal fun setUp(restDocumentationContextProvider: RestDocumentationContextProvider) {
    RestAssured.port = port
    spec = RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setConfig(
            RestAssuredConfig.config()
                .objectMapperConfig(
                    ObjectMapperConfig.objectMapperConfig()
                        .jackson2ObjectMapperFactory { _, _ -> mapper }
                )
        )
        .addFilter(defaultDocument)
        .addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter())
        .log(LogDetail.ALL)
        .build()
}
```

where `mapper` and `port` are injected as `Spring` beans.

The server generates a `Date` header, which is the time when the response is generated. This is done automatically by `Spring WebMvc` (I think) and I don't care at all for that header. However, the `Date` header causes stub generation to fail, as I decided to use [Spring Cloud Contracts in a polyglot world approach](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world) to generate and upload stub to maven repository, because now the server generates a different date.

As I point out [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/455#issuecomment-432626484), the [ContractDslSnippet](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/v2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-wiremock/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/wiremock/restdocs/ContractDslSnippet.java#L113) does not seem to provide a way to ignore unimportant headers and/or to add matchers (which would still an open question).

The (short) list of questions:

- How can I filter out unimportant headers from generated contracts?
- Can I add custom matchers for headers, like I can do for body?

Comment: Spring MVC doesn’t add a `Date` header. It’s probably coming from whatever you’re using as the HTTP server. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292132/1384297, for example.

Answer (score 0):

How to remove unimportant header, using [Spring RestDocs preprocessors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/api/org/springframework/restdocs/operation/preprocess/Preprocessors.html):

```
private val defaultDocument = document("{method_name}", SpringCloudContractRestDocs.dslContract())
lateinit var spec: RequestSpecification
@BeforeEach
internal fun setUp(restDocumentationContextProvider: RestDocumentationContextProvider) {
    RestAssured.port = port
    spec = RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setConfig(
            RestAssuredConfig.config()
                .objectMapperConfig(
                    ObjectMapperConfig.objectMapperConfig()
                        .jackson2ObjectMapperFactory { _, _ -> mapper }
                )
        )
        .addFilter(
            documentationConfiguration(restDocumentationContextProvider)
                .operationPreprocessors()
                .withResponseDefaults(Preprocessors.removeMatchingHeaders("Date"))
        )
        .addFilter(defaultDocument)
        .addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter())
        .log(LogDetail.ALL)
        .build()
}
```

The important part is adding a new filter (the first one), which takes care of configuring `Spring RestDocs` to remove the `Date` from all its snippets, including the contract ones.

How to add custom matchers, using the default `SpringCloudContractRestDocs.dslContract()`: I don't think it is actually possible right now, but might be wrong here (glad if somebody can chime in and correct me in case)